# APN and Ad-Hoc Builds

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I hope this is not a question that has been asked 1000x, I couldn't find a good answer.

In order to distribute apps to our testers we use ad-hoc builds. The trouble we are having is that APN stopped working for the ad-hoc builds. The servers that are used by the adhoc builds are using the production push SSL certificate and production service endpoints.

My questions:

1.) Does apple permit using the production APNS if the app is not distributed via the app store? Do you need an enterpise account for that?

2.) Are there proven recipes to track down errors? The feedback service from apple has not returned anything ever.

Thanks for any feedback,
Stan

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive that it is a requirement (though I believe so), but we have sent notifications using the production cert from an enterprise account.

The feedback service will tell you if a token is no longer good, but in general it fails silently once the request has been successfully sent off to Apple (your framework can provide errors such as ports being blocked etc.).

Comment: enterprise and adhoc works? great! I think this limitation makes sense, otherwise APN would be open to any app not actually on the store. The feedback service is silent unfortunately.

Comment: The feedback service is still useful in that it will tell you which tokens are no longer valid (e.g., the user deleted the app).  It is still a good idea to query this and deactivate the tokens that it reports in your back end database.